# Address custom field in the unlocked package

Tags: unlocked-package

is it possible to include custom address fields in the unlocked package? Currently, we received an error "Invalid data type" when tried to create a package version.

Comment: As per [doc](https://dx-extended-coverage.my.salesforce-sites.com/docs/metadata-coverage/58), I don't think custom address field is supported in unlocked package.

Comment: Seems like you are right. Is that official Salesforce doc?

Comment: Yes, will post same as an answer so that it can help others too.

Comment: For managed package  please use  this flag ```--definition-file DEFINITION-FILE config\project-scratch-def.json```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per metadata coverage [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/58), custom address field is not supported in unlocked packaging.